# CI/CD Pipeline -> scratch org -> force:apex:test:run -> portal account owner must have a role

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

I run a tests in GitLab PipeLine

`sfdx force:apex:test:run --wait 10 --resultformat human --codecoverage --testlevel RunLocalTests`

and get error

**System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, portal account owner must have a role: []**

If I understand correctly, an additional parameter is needed when creating a scratch org.
Thanks to everyone who answers.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Scratch Org, it is pre-populated with OOTB Roles. However, these Roles are broken and cannot be used. To allow certain types of test to execute successfully you need to make sure to assign a custom role to the "User User".

We did this using some scripting. You can use the sfdx CLI commands to achieve this. Since we were already using Ant we scripted that way. You can see further details in [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/258323/50252) in a previous question.